# Regularly changing audio element source causes popping/stuttering

Tags: javascript, html, audio, media, html5-audio

I am working on a project which requires me to proxy audio data from client A to client B. See it as client A talking through their microphone to client B with a server in the middle so no IP addresses can be spoofed. The way how I am dealing with this issue is by recording input audio of client A, output the recorded audio every 150 milliseconds to a WAVE (.wav) audio file and then forwarding it to client B. The problem I am currently facing is that each time client B receives that new audio file and plays it, there is a tiny stutter/pop/pause between the previously played chunk of audio and the one it just received (client B won't be able to recognise words anymore, it is that bad). At first, I thought of solving this problem by making the audio chunks larger so fewer pops occur, the problem with that is that it increases the delay between client A sending audio and client B receiving it and latency is of importance here.

Client A's code (sender):

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false}).then(function(mediaStream) {

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);
    mediaRecorder.mimeType = "audio/wav";

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (blob) {
        //  Turn blob (short wav file) into string and send it to server which forwards it to client B
        sendToServer(MakeDataURL(blob));
    };

    mediaRecorder.start(150);

}).catch(function(err) {
    alert(err);
});
```

Client B's code (receiver):

```
var audioElement = document.querySelector("audio");

serverConnection.on("message", function(audioAsDataUrl) {   
    //  Works but audio pops each time this is called :(     
    audioElement.src = audioAsDataUrl;
});
```

As you can tell the code is simplified but everything works apart from this audio popping or whatever it is called.

Is there a way I can get rid of this pop after changing the audio element's source when a new audio chunk is received from the proxy server?